# Should I use orthogonal view or perspective to create geometry on a scene matched with fSpy?

Tags: modeling, camera, fspy

I used fSpy to initially set up the camera in the kitchen scene I am creating. Should I place the kitchen appliances using the orthogonal grid and then tweak the fSpy camera settings to get the correct vanishing points in the scene, or should I place the appliances using a non-orthogonal grid?

Comment: Yes this was very helpful. Thanks!